# Makefile to rebuild during header file changes

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to write a Makefile for a project. With that, I was able to build the project whenever there is a change in any of the C files. But, it doesn't build when there is a change in a header file.

So, I'm trying Makefile for a simpler directory structure and if it works I'm planning to do the same in the main project.

The directory structure is,

```
src -> code1 -> file1.c
src -> code2 -> file2.c
src -> code1inc -> file1.h
src -> code2inc -> file2.h
```

All the files together should build and give a single binary `FinalBin`

When there is a change in file1.h, it has to build only file1.c. 
How do I impose this through the Makefile?

This is my current Makefile.

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES)

TARGET = FinalBin

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)

PATH_CODE1 = src/code1
PATH_CODE2 = src/code2

CODE1_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(PATH_CODE1)/*.c)
CODE1_OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(CODE1_SOURCES))

CODE2_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(PATH_CODE2)/*.c)
CODE2_OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(CODE2_SOURCES))

PATH_CODE1INC = src/code1inc
PATH_CODE2INC = src/code2inc

INCLUDES = -I$(PATH_CODE1INC) \
                -I$(PATH_CODE2INC)

CODE1_HEADERS := $(wildcard $(PATH_CODE1INC)/*.h)
CODE2_HEADERS := $(wildcard $(PATH_CODE2INC)/*.h)

all: $(TARGET)

obj1 = $(CODE1_OBJECTS) $(CODE1_HEADERS)
obj2 = $(CODE2_OBJECTS) $(CODE2_HEADERS)

$(TARGET) : $(obj1) $(obj2)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@

clean:
        rm $(TARGET) $(CODE1_OBJECTS) $(CODE2_OBJECTS)
```

Please guide me in this.

Comment: Make `$(CODE1_OBJECTS)` *depend* on `$(CODE1_HEADERS)`? And if that can be multiple object files and header files, you have to list the dependencies explicitly.

Comment: It is better to use `-MD -MF` keys to `gcc` to generate headers dependency files and then include those to your makefile.
I have done that in my templates for non-recursive make, you can have a look and possiblu use my templates: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed statements in the rule are not needed. Gcc supports the -MF option to control the dependency output file.

```
CC = gcc
SRCS = foo.c bar.c ...
OBJS = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
DEPS = $(wildcard $(OBJS:%=%.d))

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -MD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o $@ -c $<

include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a simpler solution!

Answer (score 2):

What you do seems unusual to me.

The typical way is to have a list of source files which can be written by hand or evaluated automatically e.g. by catching all c files from one or more directories. That is what you already do with: `CODE1_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(PATH_CODE1)/*.c)`

But the dependencies for each file should be generated automatically. For example gcc provides the '-M' or '-MM' option to rebuild the so called dependency files, typically named '.d' or '.dep'

A good document for the complete process can be found here:

http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#basic

For the simple case this is an example taken from the above document:

```
SRCS = foo.c bar.c ...

%.o : %.c
    @$(MAKEDEPEND); \
      cp $*.Td $*.d; \
      sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
          -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $*.Td >> $*.d; \
      rm -f $*.Td
    $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<

include $(wildcard $(SRCS:.c=.d))
```

If using gcc MAKEDEPEND can be:

```
MAKEDEPEND = gcc -M $(CPPFLAGS) -o $*.Td $<
```

A short explanation:

In general you define the rule how a %.o file is generated from a %.o file with:

```
%.o : %.c
```

As the first step in that rule you build the depfile always if the source must be compiled, typically if the %.o file did not exist OR the dependencies are newer than the %.o file with:

```
gcc -M $(CFLAGS) -o $*.Td $<
```

The last line given from the excerpt did include all these automatically generated dependency files by simply including them into the Makefile itself with:

```
include $(wildcard $(SRCS:.c=.d))
```

Comment: That `$(CPPFLAGS)` should be `$(CFLAGS)` since it's compiling C code not C++ code

Comment: @ChrisTurner: Fixed that! Thanks